# Building and installing Mozilla signtool on Windows 7

Tags: windows, signtool

Can anyone either point me to (or provide here) a clear, step-by-step approach that will get Mozilla's signtool (distinct from the Windows program of the same name) installed and working in a Windows environment (specifically, Windows 7)?  It appears to be the best tool available to build a XPI file to package up a compiled Firefox extension (in this case, a plugin developed in C++ with Visual Studio). There are quite a few purported explanations on the web of how to do this, but I've tried following several now, and each seems to be missing major steps. For what it's worth, I don't care whether I start from source, download binaries to my dev machine, or do whatever else, just so long as it gets me a usable, properly installed signtool so I can use it to package my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Signing_a_XPI is on the mark, in stark contrast to many other web pages on the topic.